# remove nex all matched selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

```
<div class="cards-list">

    <input type="text" id="6KfwRH7tWeE8Xcoru" class="card-input inputtitle" placeholder="Card" autocapitalize="none" autocorrect="off" style="background: rgb(255, 255, 224);">

    <input type="text" id="3t2KbWkdcssycX4ZA" class="card-input inputtitle" placeholder="Card" autocapitalize="none" autocorrect="off" style="background: rgb(255, 255, 255);">

</div>

<div class="childcards-container">
    <div class="cards-list child-cards-list">

            <input type="text" id="tR97tczPcrn544xP2" class="form-control card-input childtitle" placeholder="Card" autocapitalize="none" autocorrect="off" style="background: rgb(255, 255, 255);">

            <input type="text" id="LLDRn83TquqFz6Z99" class="form-control card-input childtitle" placeholder="Card" autocapitalize="none" autocorrect="off" style="background: rgb(255, 255, 255);">

    </div>
    <div class="cards-list child-cards-list">

            <input type="text" id="a846ePXd64eEgNeva" class="form-control card-input childtitle" placeholder="Card" autocapitalize="none" autocorrect="off" style="background: rgb(255, 255, 255);">

    </div>
    <div class="cards-list child-cards-list">

            <input type="text" id="cTSKTBtmFaikLsayM" class="form-control card-input childtitle" placeholder="Card" autocapitalize="none" autocorrect="off" style="background: rgb(255, 255, 255);">

    </div>
</div>
```

that is my code and when I click on `.inputtitle`  in `.cards-list` div

I want to delete all the next occurenece of `.child-cards-list` divs

I'm working with meteor and my event handler is

```
'click .inputtitle':function(e,tmpl){
        $(e.currentTarget).nextAll('.child-cards-list').remove();
    },
```

but it's not working what are the other alternative ways to do it?

Comment: I am not sure about your html structure. You have one div that contains two input with `inputtitle` class. When either is clicked, you just want to destroy (or hide) div with `childcards-container` class?

Comment: I want to remove all `.child-cards-list` class not `childcards-container`

Comment: but the `.child-cards-list` divs that you want to remove will be always in `childcards-container` div?

Comment: yes but if someone clicks on `.childtitle` text box I want to remove next occurences of `.child-cards-list` classes too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

To delete every occurrences except the selected:

```
$(".childtitle").click(function(){
   var parent = $(this).parent();
   $(".child-cards-list").not(parent).remove();
});
```

To delete the next occurences:

```
$(".childtitle").click(function(){
   $(this).parent().nextAll(".child-cards-list").remove();
});
```